# How i can backup data from VMware to tape?

Tags: backup, command-line-interface, vmware-esxi, vmware-server, tape

i have more than one VM ware hosted on ESX 3.5I and i want to connect it (VMware) to tape to make backup from vmware to tape .... I can do it? .... if yes HOW ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the [VMWare Consolidated Backup](http://www.vmware.com/products/vi/consolidated_backup.html) option. Be warned that it is not a trivial exercise to get it working. IIRC you still have to combine this with another backup product and a "proxy" machine to get the backups onto tape.